# Using few functions in Haskell together

Tags: haskell

I made this code where I need to find elements in a list that appears only once
for example: for input [1,2,2,3,4,4], the output will be: [1,3]

```
unique ::      =[a]->[a]
unique xs      =[x|x<-xs, elemNum x xs ==1]

elemNum ::      Int -> [Int]->[Int]
elemNum x  (y:ys)   
              | x==y         =1+ elemNum x ys
              | otherwise  =elemNum x ys
```

However I am getting an error : 
      Not in scope: `unique'

Is this the correct way to use 2 function in Haskell? (define them at the same file), What'a wrong with the code?

Comment: I get a parse error on the `=` in the first line. After fixing that, I get type errors. Because you only mention a 'not in scope' error, it sounds like you're trying to use `unique` in another file or in ghci without loading/importing the definitions (so they don't get parsed/type checked).

Comment: I just saved this file under the name unique.hs, then I loaded it, and then I run the query unique [1,1,2,3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. type signature of `unique` is wrong, it should be

   unique :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]

   that type constraint (`Eq a`) comes from `elemNum`
2. type signature of `elemNum` also wrong, it should be

   elemNum :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int

   that type constraint comes from `==`, and the type of its first parameter no need to be `Int`, but its return type should be `Int` because you want to find out how many `x` in `xs`.

   Also, you forgot to deal with empty list in that definition.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
unique :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
unique xs      =[x| x<-xs, elemNum x xs == 1]

elemNum :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
elemNum x [] = 0
elemNum x  (y:ys)   
              | x==y       = 1 + elemNum x ys
              | otherwise  = elemNum x ys
```

---

Here is another implementation:

```
onlyOnce [] = []
onlyOnce (x:xs)
    | x `elem` xs = onlyOnce $ filter (/=x) xs
    | otherwise = x : onlyOnce xs
```

If `x` occurs in `xs`, then the result of `onlyOnce (x:xs)` should be the same as the result of applying `onlyOnce` to the result of removing all occurrences of `x` from `xs`; otherwise, `x` occurs in `(x:xs)` only once, so `x` should be part of the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You have an equals sign in the Type declaration for `unique`:

```
unique ::      =[a]->[a]
```

should be

```
unique :: [a] -> [a]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is much easier to implement this function using functions from `Data.List` module:

```
import Data.List
unique :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
unique = map (\(y,_) -> y) . filter (\(x,l) -> l == 1) . map (\l@(x:xs) -> (x,length l)) . group . sort
```

Comment: `(\(y,_) -> y)` is `fst`. `(\(x,l) -> l == 1)` is `((==1).snd)`. you could shorten the definition to just `concat . filter ((==1).length) . group . sort`, or `f xs = [x | [x] <- group $ sort xs]`. But any solution with `sort` will potentially change the order of elements.